# Deploying Branches with Rails, Capistrano 3.0, SVN, & Jenkins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svn, jenkins, capistrano, subversive

I am attempting to deploy a specific branch on my rails application from a Subversion repository using Capistrano 3 and Jenkins. The application deploys perfectly, but no matter what I do, it only deploys the trunk.

In rails I have tried setting...

```
set :repo_url, "svn://XX.X.X.XXX/REPO/"
set :svn_location, "branches/BRANCH_NAME"
```

and...

```
set :repo_url, "svn://XX.X.X.XXX/REPO/branches/BRANCH_NAME"
```

and in Jenkins I have set the repository to...

```
svn://XX.X.X.XXX/REPO/branches/BRANCH_NAME
```

...with no success. Lastly, I've gone through the Jenkins log and there is no mention of the trunk... only the branch.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.